# Minimum iOS deployment version of flutter package

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have written a flutter package for local use and I am trying to get the minimum deployment version working so that no devices < 11.0 can use it.

I have set the following in the library using xcode (never sure whether to use xCode or edit the files manually)

[image]

And also have edited the libraries ios/<LIBRARY_NAME>.podspec file manually to have the following

```
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.platform = :ios, '11.0'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'
```

When i ran pod install (also tried pub get) in the IOS directory of an app using the library it prints the following

```
[!] The platform of the target `Runner` (iOS 9.0) may not be compatible with `<LIBRARY_NAME> (x.x.x)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 11.0.
```

And I have also set the app to have ios 9.0 (which should error) in the ios/Podfile

e.g.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

When I run the app builds, installs and runs fine. I have also tried cleaning the pod cache in between pod installs.

Can somebody explain what I have done wrong or am missing, trial and error isn't really working when the builds are like 5-10 minutes :(

Also I don't really understand what `s.platform = :ios, '11.0'` is setting in the iOS podspec when there is also deployment_target?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change 9.0 to 11.0 in your pod file.

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```